# Stripe API 2022-11-15 charge .refunds and charge.refunded webhook event

Tags: stripe-payments

In my app, I listen for charge.refunded (https://stripe.com/docs/api/events/types#event_types-charge.refunded) webhook and read .refunds of the received object to see how much exactly was refunded up to the date.

With the new Stripe API version https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-11-15 they removed .refunds from the `charge` object though.

This seems to lead to a seemingly absurd situation, where in a 'refund' event I have to go around calling Stripe API additionally expanding on .refunds of the charge.

This looks unreasonable at the least.

I wonder if my understanding of getting .refunds from a charge.refunded event is indeed correct, and we absolutely have to do it this way now.

Note that not upgrading API version is not an option for me, I'd like to keep it the last version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct about the current behavior. It has been confirmed by Stripe staff member on their dev-help channel on Discord:

> That event is the only one to get that information. That being said,
> the refunds list has to be expanded (see here:
> https://stripe.com/docs/expand) in order for the Refunds to show up.
>
> **Since you can't expand webhook events, you have to make a separate API
> call to Stripe to retrieve the Charge object with the refunds list
> expanded instead.**

Source: https://discord.com/channels/841573134531821608/1045113399719247903/1045117243412975686